# cannot launch node of type [rocon_interactions/interactions_manager.py]

Tags: ros, turtlebot, rocon, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to the turtlebot and have setup both my workstation and the turtlebot as described in the tutorial. Both machines are running Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo Igloo. I've been dashing my head against some errors for a while and haven't found any similar posts on the forums. If anyone has suggestions I'd appreciate them.

When I run on the turtlebot:

> roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch

and on the workstation:

> rqt -s kobuki_dashboard

to bringup the dashboard I can see the colour of the battery, warnings, and other features along the top. However, the content is grey and I get errors and warnings as follows:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rocon_interactions/interactions_manager.py]: rocon_interactions
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/turtlebot/turtlebot/src
ROS path [2]=/home/turtlebot/kobuki/src
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
process[zeroconf/zeroconf-12]: started with pid [23290]
[ INFO] [1413372214.521591475]: Zeroconf: service successfully established [turtlebot][_ros-master._tcp][11311]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bondpy/bondpy.py:114: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.pub = rospy.Publisher(self.topic, Status)
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bondpy/bondpy.py:114: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.pub = rospy.Publisher(self.topic, Status)
```

```
 [WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.117538] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/xbox360_teleop'.  'turtlebot_rapps/xbox360_teleop' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.117850] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/map_manager'.  'turtlebot_rapps/map_manager' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.118237] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/follower'.  'turtlebot_rapps/follower' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.118565] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/map_nav'.  'turtlebot_rapps/map_nav' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.118891] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/3dsensor'.  'turtlebot_rapps/3dsensor' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.119216] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/ps3_teleop'.  'turtlebot_rapps/ps3_teleop' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.119541] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'rocon_apps/video_teleop'.  'turtlebot_rapps/video_teleop' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.119863] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/make_a_map'.  'turtlebot_rapps/make_a_map' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.120179] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'rocon_apps/listener'.  'rocon_apps/listener' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.120533] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/panorama'.  'turtlebot_rapps/panorama' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.120855] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'rocon_apps/chirp'.  'rocon_apps/meow_chirp' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.121138] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/auto_docking'.  'turtlebot_rapps/auto_docking' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1413372218.121417] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'rocon_apps/talker'.  'rocon_apps/talker' has been selected.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195018/cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Brocon_interactions/interactions_manager.py%5D/) by [Kongaloosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20476/kongaloosh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know what caused the issue, but I wiped , reinstalled, and re-made everything and it worked.

---

Originally posted by [Kongaloosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20476/kongaloosh/) with karma: 41 on 2014-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-10-27**:
Could you mark it as resolved if it is no longer problem?

**Comment by [Kongaloosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20476/kongaloosh/) on 2014-10-28**:
I tried, but it doesn't let me accept my own answer.

**Comment by [dfk](https://answers.ros.org/users/21627/dfk/) on 2015-03-10**:
What exactly did you wipe? ROS? or Turtlebot packages?

**Comment by [Minglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23257/minglong/) on 2015-09-22**:
I also want to know what you wiped? All the ROS system?